# java, apache-camel,cassandra, jboss fuse

Tags: java, maven, jboss, cassandra, apache-camel

From my existing application, i am trying to connect to caasandra but facing some maven issues. Here is what i did:

Added in Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-cassandraql</artifactId>
  <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
  <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

In camel:

```
<route="test">
    <to uri="cql://127.0.0.1/empdetails?cql=select * from employee;&amp;consistencyLevel=quorum"/>
</route>
```

But i am experiencing :

```
Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-9" 
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreate 
1/empdetails?cql=select * from employee;&consistencyLevel=quorum] <<< in route:
Route(test)[[From[direct:route      
mpdetails?consistencyLevel=quorum&cql=select+*+from+employee%3B due to:
No component found with scheme: cql "
```

I am i on the right track, please suggest me.

Comment: implemented in reference to  http://camel.apache.org/cassandra.html

Comment: Are you sure that version of redhat camel actually supports that component? You should ask Fuse support.

Comment: @ Souciance Eqdam Rashti , OK i will check. Is this the correct way to write caasendra realted route <to uri="cql://127.0.0.1/empdetails?cql=select ....>    or         <to uri="cassandra:cassandraConnection?keyspace=empdetails&amp;table=employee& ....>  any idea ?

Comment: The documentation says how the uri should look but I doubt that version of redhat camel actually supports that component if you are getting error, alternatively your maven repo hasn't fetched it. Check your maven repo if the component is installed.

Comment: I have checked with the redhat support and got it resolved. But, for this cassandra route <to uri="cql://cassandra/test?cql=select * from users;&amp;consistencyLevel=quorum" /> I am facing  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Prepared statement has only 0 variables, 1 values provided
 at com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement.bind(BoundStatement.java:140)[556:com.datastax.driver.core:2.1.5]  

 Suggestions please